# Can we directly point to a node from Eclipse AST instead of visiting all the nodes

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to parse a java file using Eclipse JDT's AST. ASTVisitor provides a nice API to traverse all the nodes and work with the node which  we want. Now what I want is, can we go to a target node, let say of type `MethodDeclaration` or all the nodes of that type, instead of traversing all the nodes? Because this reduces time if I have to get all the nodes of a particular type in a whole package. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Finding all nodes of a given type inherently *is* traversing. `ASTVisitor` is suitable for this exact task.

If you are concerned about unnecessary traversal *below* the node you are interested in, just return `false` from the corresponding `visit()` method, and the visitor will not descend into children of the current node.

I'd be surprised, though, if traversing actually were a performance bottleneck. Creating the AST in the first place is more expensive than that.

If you only want to address few nodes (identified, e.g., by a name pattern), then performing a **search** (which relies on an index) could perhaps be faster, but this probably pays off only if a significant number of files can be skipped entirely.

Finally, as you mention `MethodDeclaration`: perhaps you don't even need AST but the Java Model (which is much more light weight) is sufficient for your task?

Comment: Did you mean "... significant number of ***nodes*** can be skipped..." in the second to last paragraph?

Comment: @FrankC., no, I meant "files", because once a file has been parsed, visiting a few more nodes shouldn't be significant. Only if search finds that an entire file is irrelevant, then not parsing this file could be significant.

Comment: @aravindkanna: a friendly reminder to consider accepting the answer. I don't think an answer that you will like better is technically possible :) and your fear of performance issues can probably be dismissed by simple measurements.